# grepping "SN", "+SN" or "-SN" exclusively without partially matching the others in R

Tags: r, regex

So I am trying to `grep` weather data from a "Weather Conditions" column that has multiple indicators for different weather types. I am trying to grep "+SN", "SN" and "-SN" separately, but am having difficulty avoiding partial matches.

Here's an example of what might be in the column to be grepped:

`c("-SN", "  ", "SN FR", "HZ +SN", "SN", "+SN", "  ", "+BC -SN")`

Grepping "-SN" is fine, but grepping "+SN" is tricky because + is a regex operator itself. Using the escape character gives me the following error:

`> grep( "\+SN" ,aa)
Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\+"`

Futhermore, grepping "SN" without getting "+SN" or "-SN" is posing a challenge. As you can see I am unable to use `^SN$` or `^SN` to exclude the + or - sign because there may be multiple indicators in one column, and the indicator I am looking for may be in front or behind another indicator. Is there a `!=` or `-v` equivalent for grep in R? How would you grep something like this? The regex in R seems more limited in its functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj i'm using grep() to select weather observations when the weather condition is either "-SN", "SN" or "+SN", so it would be inside a subsetting expression like `df[ grep("-SN", df$col ) , ]` . I'm just having difficulties with the grep portion.

Comment: As for the `+`, I think you need to escape the escape char, i.e. `grep('\\+SN', aa)`, for the plain 'SN', search for a string that starts with `'SN'` or has a whitespace char followed by 'SN': `grep('(^SN|\\sSN)', aa)`. See [example here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=SD2ksmB6&version=1).

Comment: @CarlGroner, that was exactly what i needed. I did not realize you had to escape the escape character itself in R. If you would like to post this as an answer i'll accept it. Would you happen to be able to point me towards a regex reference in R? The ?grep site is not very helpful.

Comment: or `grep( "[+]SN" ,aa)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookaround based regex.

```
> x <- c("-SN", " ", "SN FR", "HZ +SN", "SN", "+SN", " ", "+BC -SN")
> regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<!\\S)[-+]?SN(?!\\S)", x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "-SN" "SN"  "+SN" "SN"  "+SN" "-SN"
```

`(?<!\\S)` Asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character.

OR

Use anchors in-order to do an exact string match.

```
> x <- c("-SN", " ", "SN FR", "HZ +SN", "SN", "+SN", " ", "+BC -SN")
> regmatches(x, regexpr("^[-+]?SN$", x))
[1] "-SN" "SN"  "+SN"
```

OR

```
> grep("^[-+]?SN$", x, value=TRUE)
[1] "-SN" "SN"  "+SN"
```

OR

To get `SN` alone, ie, `SN` which was not preceded by a `+` or `-`

```
> x <- c("-SN", " ", "SN FR", "HZ +SN", "SN", "+SN", " ", "+BC -SN")
> regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<![+-])SN\\b", x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "SN" "SN"
```

Comment: I am actually looking to grep "SN", "-SN" and "+SN" exclusively in 3 different statements (ie for one statement, I want to grep SN but not "-SN" or "+SN"). However, I did not realize `grep` had a `perl` argument, which would probably allow me to grep what i need!

Comment: OMG, still i don't know what's your expected output is, added there answers. Hope it helps. `ie for one statement, I want to grep SN but not "-SN" or "+SN")` could you explain why?